# Unix find directory with missing file

Tags: unix, find

How can I use `find` to identify those directories that do not contain a file with a specified name? I want to create a file that contains a list of all directories missing a certain file.

Comment: This *might* (I'm not sure) be better suited to [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Find directories:

```
find -type d > DIRS
```

Find directories with the file:

```
find -type f -name 'SpecificName' | sed 's!/[^/]*$!!' > FILEDIRS
```

Find the difference:

```
grep DIRS -vf FILEDIRS
```

Comment: `find -type f -name "SpecificName" -exec dirname {} \; | uniq` use this a much simple way to extract unique dirnames containing the file. Use the same trick with directories.

Comment: Use `grep -F` or `fgrep` if the list of directories is long (e.g. >10000) to speed things up.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few different ways you could go about this - here's the approach I would take (`bash` assumed):

```
while read d
do
  [[ -r ${d}/SpecificFile.txt ]] || echo ${d}
done < <(find . -type d -print)
```

If your target directories only exist at a certain depth, there are other options you could add to `find` to limit the number of directories to check...

Answer (score 0):

This is an example for a file main.cpp. In the example all directories that do not contain main.cpp in them are found. As you see I first get a list of all folders, then get a list of folders having main.cpp and then run `diff` to get a difference between the two lists:

```
diff  \
  <(find . -exec readlink -f {} \; | sed 's/\(.*\)\/.*$/\1/' | sort | uniq) \
  <(find . -name main.cpp  -exec readlink -f {} \; | sed 's/\(.*\)\/.*$/\1/' | sort | uniq) \
  | sed -n 's/< \(.*\)/\1/p'
```